# Regex to ignore Semicolon

Tags: python, regex

I have one column in a dataframe with key value pairs I would like to extract.

```py
'AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619'
```

I would like to parse key value pairs like so

```py
('AF_ESP', '0.00546')
('AF_EXAC', '0.00165')
('AF_TGP', '0.00619')
```

Here is my regex.

```
([^=]+)=([^;]+)
```

This gets me most of way there:

```
('AF_ESP', '0.00546')
(';AF_EXAC', '0.00165')
(';AF_TGP', '0.00619')
```

How can I adjust it so semicolons are not captured in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consume the semi-colon or start of string in front:

```
(?:;|^)([^=]+)=([^;]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/USMbWz/1). *Details*:

- `(?:;|^)` - a non-capturing group matching `;` or start of string
- `([^=]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `=`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `([^;]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `;`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9yc0VO):

```py
import re
text = "AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619"
print( re.findall(r'(?:;|^)([^=]+)=([^;]+)', text) )
# => [('AF_ESP', '0.00546'), ('AF_EXAC', '0.00165'), ('AF_TGP', '0.00619')]
```

A non-regex solution is also possible:

```py
text = "AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619"
print( [x.split('=') for x in text.split(';')] )
# => [['AF_ESP', '0.00546'], ['AF_EXAC', '0.00165'], ['AF_TGP', '0.00619']]
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ny8TEZ).

Answer (score 0):

This can be also solved with a `split` method:

```py
text = "AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619"
print([tuple(i.split('=')) for i in text.split(';')])
```

output:

```
[('AF_ESP', '0.00546'), ('AF_EXAC', '0.00165'), ('AF_TGP', '0.00619')]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate and somewhat simpler approach to @Wiktor's solution is, in steps:

1. Capture everything until the `=`.
2. Get the `=` but don't capture that.
3. Get everything after the `=` up until an optional `;` if that exists.

This would translate to the following regex:

- [`([^=]+)=([^;]+);?`](https://regex101.com/r/nN0edo/1)

[image]

And in python:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^=]+)=([^;]+);?', "AF_ESP=0.00546;AF_EXAC=0.00165;AF_TGP=0.00619")
[('AF_ESP', '0.00546'), ('AF_EXAC', '0.00165'), ('AF_TGP', '0.00619')]
```